# Not getting solution to simple equation

Tags: equation-solving

qThis is my code.

```
R = 12.17 
g = 9.8
θ = 36 Degree
Solve[R==v*cos[θ]*(v*sin[θ]+sqrt[(v*sin[θ])^\.1d2 \[Minus] 2*g]), v]`
```

What is the problem with this code?

Comment: Built-in function such as `Cos` and `Sqrt` use upper case.

Comment: Solve[R == v*Cos[θ]*(v*Sin[θ] + Sqrt[(v*Sin[θ])^2 \[Minus] 2*g]), v]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you correct the syntax errors and the bad characters in you code, it works fine.

```
R = 12.17;
g = 9.8;
θ = 36. Degree;
Solve[R == v Cos[θ] (v Sin[θ] Sqrt[(v Sin[θ])^2 - 2 g]), v]
```

> ```
> {{v -> -7.57021}, {v -> 7.57021}}
> ```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks..